# Three.js MeshBasicMaterial doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, texture-mapping

I am trying to  create a texture with Three.js.

My source of texture_f1 is a .png file witch means you can see the background through it.

The problem is that if i try to set background `color: 0xffffff` it doesn't
work in combination with  map:.

If i set only the `color:0xffffff` , it return a white, but when use with map: like this `var material_f1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture_f1, color: 0xffffff});` i can see the background through the .png black .

Answer (score 3):

If you have a transparent texture, you must set `material.transparent` to `true`.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    map: texture,
    transparent: true
} )
```

Note that the material color does not "show through" the transparent texture -- it *tints* the texture.

If you want the material color to "show through" the transparent texture, then you need to use `ShaderMaterial`, instead, and create a custom shader.

There is an example of doing that in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781064/three-js-multiple-materials-on-object-loaded-via-objmtlloader/16781472#16781472).

three.js r.71

Comment: please accept then answer then too, makes it easier to find unanswered ones here :)